Run docker container and python script in Airflow
So I have a Scrapy project, which I was able to containerize in Docker, and a Jupyter notebook (for normal data preprocessing). I want to automate both of them using Airflow but encountered several errors.
Firstly, I tried using dockeroperator and bashoperator, both of which gave me errors for the Scrapy Docker container. For the notebook file, I tried using papermill and nbclient, but both also resulted in errors.
I am on Windows and using WSL for Airflow processes. Even though Papermill was installed and configured, it still says no module found.
Here is the error message:
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/my_dag.py]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/my_dag.py", line 3, in <module>
    from airflow.providers.papermill.operators.papermill import PapermillOperator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.papermill'.

For this error, I installed the module in various ways, but it still doesn't work.
Here is my DAG file:
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker import DockerOperator
from airflow.providers.papermill.operators.papermill import PapermillOperator
from datetime import timedelta

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG(
    'justwatch_scrape_and_enrich',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Scrape and enrich data',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
)

scrape_data = DockerOperator(
    task_id='scrape_data',
    image='proj-scrapy',
    container_name='scrape_data_container',
    command='docker run --network host -v "$(pwd):/app" -p 6800:6800 proj-scrapy',
    volumes=[('/mnt/airflow/data', '/app/data')],
    network_mode='host',
    dag=dag,
)

enrich_data = PapermillOperator(
    task_id="enrich_data",
    input_nb="/mnt/airflow/contentIDmap.ipynb",
    output_nb=f"/mnt/airflow/enriched_contentIDmap_{{{{ execution_date }}}}.ipynb",
    parameters={"date": "{{ execution_date }}"},
    dag=dag,
)

What am I doing wrong?
I am expecting the DAG to run and produce a final CSV file as output after scraping the data and performing some preprocessing tasks. Next, I want to run this on AWS so that it can be remotely accessed by others.

Consulting the official docs there is an example dag.
According to it you should modify your import:
from: from airflow.providers.papermill.operators.papermill import PapermillOperator
to: from airflow.operators.papermill_operator import PapermillOperator
Here is a link to the official example.
